# javascript: convert date and time strings to UTC

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have had a truly gnarly time trying to work with `Date` objects in javascript, which strike me as ugly and unintuitive.

I am getting back two objects from an internal API: one `date` string in the form of `YYYY-MM-DD` and one `time` string in the form of `HH:MM`.

What I want to do, in javascript, is to merge these into a UTC-formatted string of the form `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:00Z`. I have been playing around a bit with the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/) and [moment timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) libraries, but I'm not sure how I might leverage these to complete this task.

Comment: Sounds like `s = s1 + s2 + ':00Z';`

Comment: use javascript   concat(); method  it will help you

Comment: var str1="2014-2-14" str2="22:10" then str3=str1.concat(str2).concat("00Z");

Comment: hi guys, I think that I actually may need to convert the time to UTC, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this thusly using moment timezone:

```
dateTime = date.concat(" ").time
dateTimeAdjusted = moment.tz(dateTime, timezone).format()
```

(where `timezone` was a variable that I had access to that contained the timezone of the given date and time.)